# I would like to be able to compare values in one CSV with a nominal set of values in another

Tags: python, c, matlab, simulink

I have been given the task of injecting faults into a system and finding deviations from a norm. These deviations will serve as the failures of the system. So far we've had to detect these faults through observation, but I would like to develop a method for:
1.) Uploading each CSV which will include a fault of a certain magnitude.
2.) Comparing the CSV containing the fault with the nominal value.
3.) Being able to print out where the failure occured, or if no failure occured at all.

I was wondering which language would make the most sense for these three tasks. We've been given the system in Simulink, and have been able to output well-formatted CSV files containing information about the components which comprise the system. For each component, we have a nominal set of values and a set of values given after injecting a fault. I'd like to be able to compare these two and find where the fault has occurred. So far we've had very little luck in Python or in Matlab itself, and have been strongly considering using C to do this.

Any advice on which software will provide which advantages would be fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: Surely the problem here is the algorithm you are using to do the comparison, not the programming language being used.  In terms of implementation what do you expect to be able to do in C that you can't do in MATLAB or Python?  Comparing values in 2 different csv files in either of those languages is almost trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the outcomes in a database, it might be worth considering a tool like Microsoft SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services) where you could use your CSV files and sets of values as data sources, compare them / perform calculations and store outcomes / datasets in tables. SSIS has an easy enough learning curve  and easy to use components as well as support for bespoke SQL / T-SQL and you can visually differentiate your components in separate processes. The package(s) can then be run either manually or in automated batches as desired.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017
Good luck!